# two parameters with SQLMAP

Tags: mysql, url, code-injection, sqlmap

i have two parameters

```
http://locahost/index.php?id=offre&o=50
```

i want sqlmap to scan the parameter **o** so i tried these solutions

```
-u http://localhost/index.php?id=offre&o=50 --skip id
-u http://localhost/index.php? --data="id=offre&o=50" -p o
```

but problem is parameter **id** required
how to scan parameter **o** and skip parameter **id** in url, 
I will be very thankful if an expert can help me out with this. Thank you. and sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

(Wanted to write a comment, but it got quite long...)

This one should test only the GET parameter `o`:

```
python sqlmap.py -u "http://localhost/index.php?id=offre&o=50" -p o
```

Which work the same as your variant with `--skip id` (are you sure it does not work?).

Your variant with `--data` performs a `POST` request instead of `GET`.

Good luck!